# List values in strings.xml

Tags: android

I would need to List all the values in strings.xml (for a given locale),
basically get a dynamic list of all the strings in an application.

My purpose here is to list all strings of all apps inside my (duely rooted) phone in order to speed up translation work.

I have no problem accessing the AssetManager of other apps :

-To get the list of all apps I use :

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

-To access the package manager I use :

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
Resources mApk1Resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(pname);
AssetManager a = mApk1Resources.getAssets();
```

But I am not quite sure where to go from here.

Obviously this is not for production purpose, just for helping my customer's translation team (you know Chinese OEMs...), so jackhammer-dirty solutions are welcome :-P (reflection, dynamic foreign context, live dex loading, dynamite etc...)

Thanks !

Edit 1 : I already know [B.A.R.T](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/b-a-r-t-helps-you-translate-android-roms-the-easy-way) it doesn't suit my need I need to do it on a live phone (not a zipped ROM) like a "live translation checker app". In particular, I don't have immediate access to the app's source codes, because I have to check a large number of phones, some being few years old. I can spend the time to root all of them if needed, but not much more.

Edit 2 : I really need something that runs on a live phone without the need of a PC. I can't modify the source code of individual apps and I can't decompile the ROM or use external tools like B.A.R.T I need an all-Java solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I guess I found it. Reflection did the trick !
Root was not even needed. Crazy to know that any apps on your phone can see all the other's ressources...

```
    public void listAllStrings(){
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        String pname = p.packageName;

        Resources packageResources=null;
        Context packageContext=null;
        try
        {   

            packageResources = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(pname);
            packageContext = MainActivity.this.createPackageContext(pname, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE + Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);                
         }
         catch(NameNotFoundException excep)
         {
             // the package does not exist. move on to see if another exists.
             Log.e(pname, "Package not found!");
         }

         Class<?> stringClass=null;
         try
         {
               // using reflection to get the string class inside the R class of the package
               stringClass = packageContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(pname + ".R$string");
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException excep1)
         {
             // Less chances that class won't be there.
             Log.e(pname, "R.string not found!");
         }
         if(stringClass!=null){
          //For every fields of the string class
          for( Field stringID : stringClass.getFields() )
          {
            try
            {
                //We get the id
                int id = stringID.getInt(stringClass);
                //We get the string value itself
                String xmlResourceLayout = packageResources.getString(id); 

                Log.v(pname, xmlResourceLayout);
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
           {
            Log.e(pname, "Can't access : "+stringID.getName());
            continue;
           }
         }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this can help others :-)

Edit : For some Apks, the R class is not at the root of the package, so I had to write a find-R function

```
    String findR(Context packageContext){
    try {
        //First case, the R class is easy to find !
        packageContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(packageContext.getPackageName() + ".R");
        return packageContext.getPackageName() + ".R";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Second case, it is not at the root of the package, we will list all classes...
        Log.v(packageContext.getPackageName(),"R not found... Continue searching !");
        try {
         final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
         ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageContext.getPackageName(), 0);

         DexFile dx = DexFile.loadDex(ai.sourceDir, File.createTempFile("opt", "dex",
                    getCacheDir()).getPath(), 0);
         String pathToR=null;
            // Search inside each and every class in the dex file
            for(Enumeration<String> classNames = dx.entries(); classNames.hasMoreElements();) {
                String className = classNames.nextElement();
                //for every single class, we will see if one of the fields is called app_name
                //Log.v(className, "Class detail : "+className);
                if(className.contains("R$string")) pathToR=className;


            }
          if(pathToR==null) throw new ClassNotFoundException();
          pathToR=pathToR.replaceAll("$string", "");
          Log.v(packageContext.getPackageName(), "R FOUND ! "+packageContext.getPackageName());
          return pathToR;
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e(packageContext.getPackageName(), "ERROR ! R NOT FOUND ...");
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

But it still doesn't work in every case. So I ended hijacking the [apktools](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool) library so it could run live on a phone... (I used the jar from 1.5.2 http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.5.2.tar.bz2&can=2&q=) Here is my hijacked class :

```
public class Decoder {
    public void decode(ResTable resTable, ExtFile apkFile, File outDir)
            throws AndrolibException {
        Duo<ResFileDecoder, AXmlResourceParser> duo = getResFileDecoder();
        ResFileDecoder fileDecoder = duo.m1;
        ResAttrDecoder attrDecoder = duo.m2.getAttrDecoder();

        attrDecoder.setCurrentPackage(resTable.listMainPackages().iterator()
                .next());

        Directory inApk, in = null, out;
        try {
            inApk = apkFile.getDirectory();
            out = new FileDirectory(outDir);

            Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Decoding AndroidManifest.xml with resources...");

            fileDecoder.decodeManifest(inApk, "AndroidManifest.xml", out,
                    "AndroidManifest.xml");

            // fix package if needed
            adjust_package_manifest(resTable, outDir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/AndroidManifest.xml");

            if (inApk.containsDir("res")) {
                in = inApk.getDir("res");
            }
            out = out.createDir("res");
        } catch (DirectoryException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException(ex);
        }

        ExtMXSerializer xmlSerializer = getResXmlSerializer();
        for (ResPackage pkg : resTable.listMainPackages()) {
            attrDecoder.setCurrentPackage(pkg);

            //Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Decoding file-resources...");
            //for (ResResource res : pkg.listFiles()) {
            //  fileDecoder.decode(res, in, out);
            //}

            Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Decoding values */* XMLs...");
            for (ResValuesFile valuesFile : pkg.listValuesFiles()) {
                generateValuesFile(valuesFile, out, xmlSerializer);
            }
            generatePublicXml(pkg, out, xmlSerializer);
            Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Done.");
        }

        AndrolibException decodeError = duo.m2.getFirstError();
        if (decodeError != null) {
            throw decodeError;
        }
    }

    public Duo<ResFileDecoder, AXmlResourceParser> getResFileDecoder() {
        ResStreamDecoderContainer decoders = new ResStreamDecoderContainer();
        decoders.setDecoder("raw", new ResRawStreamDecoder());
        //decoders.setDecoder("9patch", new Res9patchStreamDecoder());
        //TODO THIS DECODER CREATES ALL PROBLEMS !
        AXmlResourceParser axmlParser = new AXmlResourceParser();
        axmlParser.setAttrDecoder(new ResAttrDecoder());
        decoders.setDecoder("xml", new XmlPullStreamDecoder(axmlParser,
                getResXmlSerializer()));

        return new Duo<ResFileDecoder, AXmlResourceParser>(new ResFileDecoder(
                decoders), axmlParser);
    }
    public static final String PROPERTY_SERIALIZER_INDENTATION = "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-indentation";
    public static final String PROPERTY_SERIALIZER_LINE_SEPARATOR = "http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-line-separator";
    public static final String PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ENCODING = "DEFAULT_ENCODING";
    public ExtMXSerializer getResXmlSerializer() {
        ExtMXSerializer serial = new ExtMXSerializer();
        serial.setProperty(PROPERTY_SERIALIZER_INDENTATION,
                "    ");
        serial.setProperty(PROPERTY_SERIALIZER_LINE_SEPARATOR,
                System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        serial.setProperty(PROPERTY_DEFAULT_ENCODING, "utf-8");
        serial.setDisabledAttrEscape(true);
        return serial;
    }

    public void adjust_package_manifest(ResTable resTable, String filePath)
            throws AndrolibException {

        // check if packages different, and that package is not equal to
        // "android"
        Map<String, String> packageInfo = resTable.getPackageInfo();
        if ((packageInfo.get("cur_package").equalsIgnoreCase(
                packageInfo.get("orig_package")) || ("android"
                .equalsIgnoreCase(packageInfo.get("cur_package")) || ("com.htc"
                .equalsIgnoreCase(packageInfo.get("cur_package")))))) {

            Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Regular manifest package...");
        } else {
            try {

                Log.v(MainActivity.SMALL_TAG,"Renamed manifest package found! Fixing...");
                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filePath.toString());

                // Get the manifest line
                Node manifest = doc.getFirstChild();

                // update package attribute
                NamedNodeMap attr = manifest.getAttributes();
                Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("package");
                mPackageRenamed = nodeAttr.getNodeValue();
                nodeAttr.setNodeValue(packageInfo.get("cur_package"));

                // re-save manifest.
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                        .newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filePath));
                transformer.transform(source, result);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
                throw new AndrolibException(ex);
            } catch (TransformerException ex) {
                throw new AndrolibException(ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new AndrolibException(ex);
            } catch (SAXException ex) {
                throw new AndrolibException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void generatePublicXml(ResPackage pkg, Directory out,
            XmlSerializer serial) throws AndrolibException {
        try {
            OutputStream outStream = out.getFileOutput("values/public.xml");
            serial.setOutput(outStream, null);
            serial.startDocument(null, null);
            serial.startTag(null, "resources");

            for (ResResSpec spec : pkg.listResSpecs()) {
                serial.startTag(null, "public");
                serial.attribute(null, "type", spec.getType().getName());
                serial.attribute(null, "name", spec.getName());
                serial.attribute(null, "id",
                        String.format("0x%08x", spec.getId().id));
                serial.endTag(null, "public");
            }

            serial.endTag(null, "resources");
            serial.endDocument();
            serial.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException("Could not generate public.xml file",
                    ex);
        } catch (DirectoryException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException("Could not generate public.xml file",
                    ex);
        }
    }

    private void generateValuesFile(ResValuesFile valuesFile, Directory out,
            ExtXmlSerializer serial) throws AndrolibException {
        try {
            OutputStream outStream = out.getFileOutput(valuesFile.getPath());
            serial.setOutput((outStream), null);
            serial.startDocument(null, null);
            serial.startTag(null, "resources");

            for (ResResource res : valuesFile.listResources()) {
                if (valuesFile.isSynthesized(res)) {
                    continue;
                }
                ((ResValuesXmlSerializable) res.getValue())
                        .serializeToResValuesXml(serial, res);
            }

            serial.endTag(null, "resources");
            serial.newLine();
            serial.endDocument();
            serial.flush();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException("Could not generate: "
                    + valuesFile.getPath(), ex);
        } catch (DirectoryException ex) {
            throw new AndrolibException("Could not generate: "
                    + valuesFile.getPath(), ex);
        }
    }

    private String mPackageRenamed = null;

}
```

and here's how I use it :

```
    String pname = p.packageName;

    Context packageContext = MainActivity.this.createPackageContext(pname, Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE + Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);    
    ApplicationInfo ai = packageContext.getApplicationInfo();

    Log.v(TAG,"Analysing : "+pname+" "+ai.sourceDir);
    if(new File(destination.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+pname+".strings.xml").exists()){
        Log.v(TAG,"Already translated...");
        continue;
    }

    ApkDecoder decoder = new ApkDecoder();
    decoder.setApkFile(new File(ai.sourceDir));

    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"tempApk");
    directory.mkdirs();
    DeleteRecursive(directory);
    directory.mkdirs();

    decoder.setOutDir(directory);

    decoder.setForceDelete(true);

    File frmwrk = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"framework");
    frmwrk.mkdirs();

    decoder.setFrameworkDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"framework");

    decoder.setDecodeSources((short)0x0000);

    decoder.setKeepBrokenResources(true);

    try{
    //decoder.decode();
        new Decoder().decode(decoder.getResTable(), new ExtFile(new File(ai.sourceDir)), directory);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Lots of headaches for few Strings ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can see that: usually the string for application label will get the first id in the resource strings. (not found an official document on this yet)

So the plan is: get the id of the label of an app, increase the id each time to get the next resource string until we get the Resources.NotFoundException

```
try {
    List<ApplicationInfo> apps = getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : apps) {
        Resources mApk1Resources = getPackageManager()
                .getResourcesForApplication(appInfo.packageName);
        int id = appInfo.labelRes;
        try {
            Log.e("Test", "*******************************************");
            Log.e("Test", apps.get(0).packageName);
            while (true) {
                Log.e("Test",
                        "String resource: "
                            + mApk1Resources.getString(id));
                id++;
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Is it me or the ressources ids always start with "0x7f0xxxxx" ?

Comment: Is there a way to access another application's R class ? And extract those ids using reflection ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you said you accept "jackhammer-dirty solutions", give this a try:

In your `Strings.xml`, surround all your String values with a `<string-array>` tag, and all `string` tags inside change to `item` tags, like so (used simple find-and-replace to replace the tag names):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="app_name">YourAppNAme</string>
     <string-array name="yourTitle">
        <item>item1</item> //used to be <string name"blabla">....
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In your xml Layout file, where you have your ListView, put:

```
<ListView
        android:id=”@+id/yourListView”
        android:layout_width=”match_parent”
        android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
        android:entries="@array/yourTitle"
    />
```

Now, your Activity where you have your List, just call the ListView which should already be populated with the items from the Strings.xml

Don't forget to revert the changes in Strings.xml once you are done (and backup is always a good idea)!

Read more [Here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm... The thing is, I have to do it on a live phone, I can't change the Strings.xml file of individual apps then recompile the ROM. My customer need me to check all the non-translated strings in all apps of his 30 existing phones.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've rooted the phone and have access to every APK in the phone, how about just decompile them and get to the strings that way, see tutorial here: http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/

Comment: I could totally do this for a phone only, but I need to do this on 20-30 phones, so I really need an app that works on a live phone.

Comment: @Taiko You can write automatic scripts to automate most of these. I personally don't know any method to retrieve every string from every app on the phone using just an app.